# Which design pattern should I use to wrap common method to entities?

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns

I'm a PHP Developer, and I'm working with Symfony2 at the moment.

I would like to present my issue as follow:

- I have 4 entities: User, Account, Customer, Merchant. All of them have status.
- I want to build a common method named 'isValid' for them, but don't want to modify their code.
- The method logic is very simple

  ```
  <!-- language: php -->
  public function isValid()
  {
      return self::STATUS_ACTIVE == $this->status;
  }
  ```
- By separate them and apply a HAS-A relation between it with entities, I think it will more flexible and maintainable. I don't have to duplicate my code to any entity need it, even in the future.

If you have experience. Could you please help me to pick a suitable pattern for this situation?

Comment: This is not a duplication that you should be worried about.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a has-a relation between these entities makes no sense, since they are not related.

However, code duplication is almost never justifiable. I would solve it by creating a common interface (`User` is-a Validatable entity, `Customer` is-a Validatable entity) and make a trait to encapsulate the common behavior.

Create the common interface:

```
interface Validatable 
{

    public function isValid(): bool;

}
```

Create a trait to implement the common behaviour:

```
trait HasStatus 
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    public function isValid(): bool
    {
        return $this->status === EntityStatus::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    }

}
```

Make your entities implement the new interface and put the trait to use to avoid duplication:

```
class User implements Validatable {
    use HasStatus;

}
```

And use it:

```
/** @var Validatable[] $validatables */
$validatables = [new User(), new Merchant(), new Customer()];

foreach ($validatables as $validatable) {
    var_dump($validatable->isValid());
}
```

Why do we need the interface? Well technically we do not need it, but I like to include it because it allows to refer to User, Customer, Merchant with a common "Validatable" typehint *and* it conveys your intention in code.

Comment: Perhaps better to put the constant in the trait?

Comment: @COil that would be considered an anti pattern [[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface)] by some

Comment: Ok. But in this example I think it is an overkill to use such a trait, I would only use it when having a more complex function.

Comment: Agreed, I think the enforcement of the interface should be enough and you should leave the actual implementation up to the class using that interface. If you want a generic validation implementation then one would simply create an abstract class which uses the interface and then extend that class (and override the function when necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Messing with this it's not a good idea,  the entity has status value, and setters/getters should be in entity file declaration. 
I understand the DRY principle but doing it on this level... it's IMHO not a good idea.

But if you are sure that all of them have status, then use a trait in a separate file:

```
trait CheckStatusTrait{
    return $this->status;
}
```

And you just add the trait to your classes:

```
class User {
   use CheckStatusTrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that simple kind of code, it would be okay do leave it duplicated in each entity, you can add an interface with "isValid" to treat them like the same from outside if necessary.

Maybe your code to check Validation would become more complex and it makes sense to have a single class which is responsible. 
Then you could make a StatusValidator class which checks if the status of a given object ist valid. It would make sense to add an interface to that kind of objects, which has a "getStatus" method, let's say the "getStatusInterface". Afterwords you can inject the StatusValidator and use it in your isValid method. Because your objects are entities, you need to use doctrine's postLoad event to inject the StatusValidator.

You also can do the same i little bit less complex by not inject the StatusValidator but ask the StatusValidator if the obejct with the getStatusInterface is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for the supports. I'm also using trait to solve code duplication. However, I see that trait seem to be not a perfect one. I had to fact to disadvantages below:

- Hiding the field in trait makes entity enigmatic. In real, not only will status field is available on many entities but also updatedDate, createdDate, type... It also looks mess when a class use many traits.
- After a development period, the trait collects more and more method,  for ex. StatusTrait can have isValid, hasStatus, setStatusDefault. But not all of entities use them. I mean some entities use isValid, some use setStatusDefault.., so we will have more mixed methods in traits. In this issue, I think that if I can implement a HAS-A relationship class, I can easily setup them at the runtime when an entity need.
- By using trait, the entity class is modified, not extension. It isn't a good practice in OOP design. The entity class isn't consistent to reference with database table. Honestly, I prefer to build logic method outside the entity class.

Aboves are my vision. I only try to find a better way to implement this issue. I hope it's also useful for everyone. I had hear about ValueObject but not really understand it obviously. I will try to figure it out!